# Transformation to another object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps

Im experementing with chrome apps and try to read from a file that is contained in the directory the user selects. So far it works good, the user selects a file and afterwards the single File Entry objects are printed into my console:

**Code:**

```
         for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
            console.log("entry is " + entries[i]);
            a = entries[i].file(callback);    
          }
```

**Console:**

```
       entry is [object FileEntry] window.js:18
       entry is [object FileEntry]
       ......
```

So how you can see from the console `entries[i]` is a `FileEntry` object.
To read from a `FileEntry` i first have to transform it to a `File` object.
In the docu for the FileEntry: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileEntry#File I read that there is a function           `void file(
  FileCallback successCallback, optional ErrorCallback errorCallback
);` That returns a file object.

How you can see in the **Code** form above i try to achieve this with that:

```
    a = entries[i].file(callback); 
......

var callback = function(){
    console.log("it works");
    console.log(a); 
}
```

**My Problem** is that `console.log(a)` does not return `object File` but instead undefined:

**Console:**

```
entry is [object FileEntry]   window.js:18
entry is [object FileEntry]   window.js:18
it works                      window.js:29
undefined                     window.js:30
it works                      window.js:29
undefined
```

**What do i wrong? How can i test if it really returns a File Object? Thanks!**

**Full Code**

```
var callback = function(){
    console.log("it works");
    console.log(a); 
} 


chooseDirButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openDirectory'}, function(theEntry) {

    chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath(theEntry, function(path) {

    var reader = theEntry.createReader();

        reader.readEntries(function(entries) {
          for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
            console.log("entry is " + entries[i]);
            a = entries[i].file(callback);    
          }
        });

    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

> var callback = function(){

To:

> var callback = function(a){

Answer (score 0):

I read ... "there is a function

```
**void** file(
  FileCallback successCallback, optional ErrorCallback errorCallback
);
```

That returns a file object."

As you see it doesn't return it, but passes as an argument to callback.  They just have a bad phrasing